# Define number of parameters in AspectJ pointcut

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'd like to define a pointcut where the only important point is that the amount of parameters of the target method. For example, I have the following pointcut definition;

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)
           && execution(* pkg..*.*(pkg.Obj1, pkg.Obj2, pkg.Obj3))")
```

I do not wish to hardcode the expected parameter types, but I only wish to get the methods with only three parameters for this pointcut. How do I achieve this with only the information that there should be three parameters for the above pointcut, without specifying the details of parameters?

For example I want it to match;

```
// in package pkg.*
@RequestMapping
public test(ObjX objX, ObjY objY, ObjZ objZ) {
   //etc
}
```

but not match the following;

```
// also in package pkg.*
@RequestMapping
public test(ObjX obj) {
   //etc
}
```

or

```
// also in package pkg.*
@RequestMapping
public test(ObjX objX, ObjY objY) {
   //etc
}
```

or

```
// also in package pkg.*
@RequestMapping
public test(ObjX objX, ObjY objY, ObjZ objZ, ObjQ objQ) {
   //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it, the way to achieve this is to give `*` as the parameters;

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)
           && execution(* xxx.yyy.zzz..*.*(*, *, *))")
```

With the similar usage of `*` for return type, other class & method names.